# How to find the correct return type for syn::parse?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-proc-macros

I have a `TokenStream` that comes from the definition of a Rust function. I want to parse it with `syn::parse` (and `.unrwap()`). However, I don't know what the return type is supposed to be:

```
let ast: ??? = syn::parse(token_stream_from_function_definition).unwrap();
```

What should the type of `ast` be?

Comment: "*that comes from the definition of a Rust function*" -- to be clear here: the token stream contains tokens which define a Rust function? For example, if you attach a custom `#[my_attr]` to a function. Is my understanding correct? Maybe you could rephrase the sentence a bit to make this more clear. Thanks!

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Yes, correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`syn::parse`](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.42/syn/fn.parse.html) function tries to parse a `TokenStream` into whatever *you* expect it to be.  As the documentation says:

> Parse tokens of source code into the chosen syntax tree node.

It takes a type parameter, which you usually provide using type inference. For example, if you were expecting to parse a function declaration:

```
let fn_decl: syn::FnDecl = syn::parse(token_stream).unwrap();
```

This would panic if it was unable to parse a `fn` declaration.

---

If you don't know exactly what to expect then you can be more general, matching a set of possibilities and then inspecting what you find. There are some enums provided for groups of syntax that can appear in the same places. For example, if you are parsing code in a context where you expect to find a function declaration *or* some other declarations on the same level, you probably need to parse an [`Item`](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.42/syn/enum.Item.html) and then match on all of the possible types of item:

```
use syn::Item;

let item: Item = syn::parse(token_stream).unwrap();
match item {
    Item::Fn(fn_decl) => {}
    Item::Mod(mod_item) => {}
    Item::Struct(struct_item) => {}
    Item::Enum(enum_item) => {}
    _ => {}
}
```

Note that `syn::Item` has 18 variants to match, and `syn::Expr` has 40! It's definitely worth narrowing down the possibilities and choosing the type to parse into that is the most specific for your needs. You might also consider defining your own type, representing the various syntactic constructs that you expect to find, and then implementing the [`syn::Parse`](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.42/syn/parse/trait.Parse.html) trait manually.

Comment: Thanks! Would there have been an easy way for me to figure out that `syn::FnDecl` is the type associated with function declaration syntax trees? Assuming I didn't have the links you gave me, how could I have found this information?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the `syn` type associated with some type you're parsing, a helpful place can be the [item](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/master/src/item.rs#L21) sourcefile.

On a broad level:

- for items in global scope, ie fn, one of [Item](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/4245c41f2210ed0ad5e80dc0fcd374e157148557/src/item.rs#L21)
- for items in a struct impl, one of [ImplItem](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/4245c41f2210ed0ad5e80dc0fcd374e157148557/src/item.rs#L781)
- for items in a trait, one of [TraitItem](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/4245c41f2210ed0ad5e80dc0fcd374e157148557/src/item.rs#L671)
- for a function argument, one of [FnArg](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/4245c41f2210ed0ad5e80dc0fcd374e157148557/src/item.rs#L928)

etc...

ie, for a function, use `ItemFn`:

```rust
let stream = quote!(fn foo(&self)->i32{0});

let a:syn::ItemFn = syn::parse2(stream).unwrap();
```